# Join paths to make one single line drawing so I can gradient the stroke

Tags: adobe-illustrator, path, gradient, stroke

I have made a drawing with the pen tool.  Most of the paths are unclosed.  I would like to put a gradient stroke on the paths.

I don't seem to be able to join all of the paths together, which I assume is the first problem to solve.  See below for my drawing.

[image: my drawing made of paths]

I believe if the strokes are all separate then at best I will gradient each stroke individually which will not give me the effect I am looking for.

I think it may also have changed because I used the shape builder to fill it originally.  So perhaps that has made a difference?

I'm using Illustrator CS5.  I have tried using Unite, Join, etc via the pathfinder.

I don't want to merge it into one shape, i want it to stay as a line drawing as the shape will never have a fill.  My intention is to put a gradient over the entire line drawing so it looks like it is shimmering.

Here is an example of what I would like to achieve (made in Photoshop).

[image: A gradient stroke]

Comment: @WELZ I'm not sure that is right.  I still just want it to be a line drawing so I don't want to join the shapes into one merged outline.  But I am sure someone has asked this before.  I just haven't found it when searching.  I'll update my question so it's clearer what I've tried.

Comment: Apply a gradient to the stroke instead of the fill? Did I misunderstand?

Comment: Yes, that is what I am trying to achieve.  You cannot gradient a stroke in CS5 (not sure if you can in CC).  The link you put shows how to merge two reflected paths into one single shape, which is not what I am trying to achieve.  Perhaps the link is not the one you thought?

Comment: Do you want all your paths to become one single path of an outline of a flamingo?

Comment: I think I need to do that because I want to apply a gradient to the drawing as a whole.  I don't want each individual stroke to have a gradient.  I updated my question with more info and another drawing.  Sorry I haven't been very clear.

Comment: See [these](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/q/76096/63979) [helpful](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/a/98665/63979) [posts](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/a/107226/63979).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Select all your shapes and set (fill and stroke) color to none and group them together

Then go to the appearance panel and click on the dropdown and choose **add new stroke**

Now just apply the gradient as the stroke.

Comment: Ok, so they were part of a live paint group.  I removed them from that group and now my paths are grouped as one.  But I cannot add a gradient to a stroke.  It will not let me select a gradient swatch in CS5.

Comment: Mind you this wont work in CS5

Comment: @joojaa that is true, you just need to expand first.

Comment: @WELZ But the asker is asking how to do it without expanding

Answer (score 2):

CS 5 can not put a gradient on a stroke, later editions can. However you can keep the objects as lines and put a gradient on them at the same time with a little known hack.

- Make a pattern with a gradient. It now possible to assign it to a stroke. You can then use the transform dialogs to rotate, translate and scale the gradient into place.

Answer (score 1):

The key here for me (in Illustrator CS5) was to select everything and then go to Object > Expand Appearance then go to Object > Expand (and make sure ONLY the stroke option is ticked).

I used this tutorial https://astutegraphics.com/blog/how-to-apply-a-gradient-fill-to-strokes-in-adobe-illustrator-cs5-and-earlier/

Once the object is expanded it becomes a shape instead of a path and you can fill it.  Once you can fill it you can use a gradient.

However, the problem that I had was the object when expanded did not cut at the anchor point.

Also to hightlight @WELZ excellent comment these answers are a better explanation.

See [Example 1](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/q/76096/63979) [Example 2](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/a/98665/63979) [Example 3](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/a/107226/63979).

Answer (score 1):

Illustrator CS5 doesn't let you put a gradient on a stoke...

My workaround is:

Duplicate the flamingo;

Expand it;

Now you can aplly the gradient.

You will have the original stroked under the copy with the gradient.